# trying to convert data into columns from row by key variables ? key variables are multiple

Tags: r

```
customer_code   cateogry
8.92e+12    CONDIMENTI PRIMI (PELATI & SUGHI)
8.92e+12    accessoro
8.92e+12    sugaro
8.92e+13    CONDIMENTI PRIMI (PELATI & SUGHI)
8.92e+13    sugaro
```

Output needed

```
customer_code CONDIMENTI PRIMI (PELATI & SUGHI)      sugaro        accessoro         
8.92e+12                5                              10              5
8.92e+13               45                              2               NA
```

Need the result in this manner.

Answer (score 1):

Use this, it can be seen as the opposite of the melt function:

```
    library(reshape2 )
    dcast(yourdata, customer_code ~ cateogry)
```

Which will result in:

```
    customer_code   accessoro   CONDIMENTI PRIMI (PELATI & SUGHI)   sugaro
1   8.92e+12        accessoro   CONDIMENTI PRIMI (PELATI & SUGHI)   sugaro
2   8.92e+13        NA          CONDIMENTI PRIMI (PELATI & SUGHI)   sugaro
```

After this you can change you column names if you want this.

Thanks to @chiwangc to make a better format of the output needed.

Comment: what if my category for a particular customer gets repeated twice, it is throwing error duplicate

Comment: and the values getting returned are numeric , basically count values i mgetting back

Comment: What do you mean with your second comment? Which values are getting returned are numeric?

Comment: the category values are returned as numeric

Comment: Start with a clean R session. The result posted is exactly what my result is.

Comment: how can i unique by rows based on two or three variables?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78732/discussion-between-michaelve-and-saugandh-datta).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the base R function [`reshape()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/reshape.html) to do this. Interestingly, your timevar doubles as a varying column, which I haven't seen before, but you can make it work by copying the column:

```
df <- data.frame(customer_code=c(8.92e+12,8.92e+12,8.92e+12,8.92e+13,8.92e+13), category=c('CONDIMENTI PRIMI (PELATI & SUGHI)','accessoro','sugaro','CONDIMENTI PRIMI (PELATI & SUGHI)','sugaro') );
reshape(transform(df,time=category),dir='w',idvar='customer_code');
##   customer_code category.CONDIMENTI PRIMI (PELATI & SUGHI) category.accessoro category.sugaro
## 1      8.92e+12          CONDIMENTI PRIMI (PELATI & SUGHI)          accessoro          sugaro
## 4      8.92e+13          CONDIMENTI PRIMI (PELATI & SUGHI)               <NA>          sugaro
```

Also, you can achieve sequential integral suffixes by coercing the factor to integer:

```
reshape(transform(df,time=as.integer(category)),dir='w',idvar='customer_code');
##   customer_code                        category.2 category.1 category.3
## 1      8.92e+12 CONDIMENTI PRIMI (PELATI & SUGHI)  accessoro     sugaro
## 4      8.92e+13 CONDIMENTI PRIMI (PELATI & SUGHI)       <NA>     sugaro
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `spread` from `tidyr` and change the column names.

```
library(tidyr)
spread(df1, cateogry, cateogry)
#  customer_code accessoro CONDIMENTI PRIMI (PELATI & SUGHI) sugaro
#1      8.92e+12 accessoro CONDIMENTI PRIMI (PELATI & SUGHI) sugaro
#2      8.92e+13      <NA> CONDIMENTI PRIMI (PELATI & SUGHI) sugaro
```

Answer (score 0):

Sample data:

```
x <- data.frame(customer = sample(100, 1000, replace = TRUE), category = sample(LETTERS, 1000, replace = TRUE))
```

With `dplyr` to produce long format:

```
 x %>% group_by(customer, category) %>% summarise(count = n())
```

With `reshape2` for wide format:

```
acast(x, customer~category)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should provide a better reproduce-able example. I suppose you are looking for frequencies of category items for each customer.

```
ID=c(8.92e+12,8.92e+13)
cat=c('CONDIMENTI PRIMI (PELATI & SUGHI)','accessoro','sugaro')
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(ID[sample(1:2,50,replace = T)], cat[sample(1:3,50,replace = T)]))

table(df[[1]], df[[2]])
```

Here is the output for simulated 50 rows:

```
          accessoro CONDIMENTI PRIMI (PELATI & SUGHI) sugaro
  8.92e+12         8                                 8     10
  8.92e+13         8                                 4     12
```